# utlizacion de combobox con base de datos

Tags: java, combobox

tengo que llenar un combox com un solo dato de la base de datos y no logro hacerlo por favor alguien que me ayude gracias e[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]esta es la imagen de mi base de datos esta el código que estoy utilizando [image: ox] y necesito que se muestre en esta parte donde dice búsqueda por fecha [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]se los voy a agradecer mil gracias esto es para finalizar mi tesis y soy principiante en este lenguaje esto todo en MYSQL

Comment: ¿`2018-00-04`? Esa fecha parece ser inválida... ¿cómo llegó allí?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo del sitio [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Answer (score 1):

Espero te sirva mi codigo bro!

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.sql.*;

class LlenaCombo extends JFrame{

 private JComboBox miCombo;

 private Connection conexion;

 private Statement sentencia;

 private ResultSet resultado;

 private String sql;

 public LlenaCombo(){

    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(AQUI PONES TU RUTA);

    sql = "SELECT DISTINCTROW DATO FROM TU BD"; 

    sentencia = conexion.createStatement(sql);

    resultado = sentencia.executeQuery();

    miCombo = new JComboBox("DATO");

    while(resultado.next()){

     miCombo.addItem(resultado.getString(1));

   }

 }
}
```

Importante:

Distinctrow: te agrega una sola columna en especifico == > los datos de esa columna.

En el bucle: el combobox se va llenando a cada vuelta de bucle con cada fila de la columna.

Comment: [Te pueden votar negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: Es importante revisar [answer], varías de tus respuestas en el sitio  se han realizado bajo el mismo formato, te sugerimos agregar y responder preguntas que sean realizadas de acuerdo al documento [answer]. saludos.

Answer (score -1):

//Sobre la clase

DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCombo = new DefaultComboBoxModel(); 
//Creo el modelo para cargar items
DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCombo2 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(); 
//Creo el modelo para cargar items

//En el constructor

jComboBox5.removeAllItems(); //Borra los items actuales
jComboBox1.removeAllItems(); //Borra los items actuales
llenar_combo(1); //Llena el combo de grupos
llenar_combo(2);

//El metodo

public void llenar_combo(int selec) {
        String informacionTabla = "";
        String informacionCampo = "";

```
    switch(selec){

        case 1:
            informacionTabla = "tabla_grupo";
            informacionCampo = "nombre_encargado";
        break;
        case 2:
            informacionTabla = "tabla_trabajo";
            informacionCampo = "nombre_trabajo";
        default:
            System.out.println("No existe opcion para el llenado del combo.");
        break;

    }

    try {
        lb = new LibreriaHerramientas();
        String Sql = "SELECT "+ informacionCampo + " as Name "
                + " FROM "
                + informacionTabla; // Escribo la sentencia !!
        PreparedStatement us = lb.conex().prepareStatement(Sql); //
        ResultSet res = us.executeQuery(); //

        if(selec == 1){
            modeloCombo.addElement("Seleccione un Campo");//es el primer registro q mostrara el combo
            jComboBox5.setModel(modeloCombo);//con esto lo agregamos al objeto al jcombobox
        }
        if(selec == 2){
            modeloCombo2.addElement("Seleccione un Campo");//es el primer registro q mostrara el combo
            jComboBox1.setModel(modeloCombo2);//con esto lo agregamos al objeto al jcombobox
        }
        while (res.next()) {

            //jComboBox5.setModel(modeloCombo);
            if(selec == 1){    
                modeloCombo.addElement(res.getObject("Name"));
                jComboBox5.setModel(modeloCombo);//con esto lo agregamos al objeto al jcombobox
            }
            if(selec == 2){
                modeloCombo2.addElement(res.getObject("Name"));
                jComboBox1.setModel(modeloCombo2);//con esto lo agregamos al objeto al jcombobox
            }

        }

        res.close();
    } catch(SQLException ex){

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución , revisar [answer],saludos.